# How to make the same state respond to multiple "elements"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hover, state-management

I have an Container which holds variable amounts of elements inside it. What I want to achieve is that whichever element is hovered on, should display the Hover Content. But with the current code all of them are displayed simultaneously no matter which one you hover on. Is there a solution to only make the content visible for the one you hover on without using multiple states.

Here is a sandbox of the code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/mystifying-sun-g4yjg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't they all have a unique key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the state is in the parent you have no distinction between which item is being hovered. Create a separate child component for your HoverBox and move the state into it (that way each box will maintain it's own hover state).

Here's a sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-rain-rhf73?file=/src/HoverBox.js

Comment: Got it. Thank you.